# how to select images randomly from oracle database using java

Tags: java, oracle

i want to display images and their information randomly to the web pages. after every some period of time it should automatically change the images and view in the browser. how can i do that using java and oracle database
i just tried to create a timer and then try to call the below query but it doesn't work

`SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  name
        FROM    employee
        ORDER BY
                dbms_random.value
        )
WHERE rownum <= 1000`

& then in the timer run method i call this query like this .

```
  TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
    public void run()
    {
     //execute the code for every 10 mins

       Timer timer = new Timer();


      timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 10 * 60 * 1000); // period is  10 mins 

       try
      {

         Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
         Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:
         @localhost:1521:orcl","Admin","secret");
         Statement st=con.createStatement();
         System.out.println("connection established successfully...!!");     

         ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT  *\n" +
  "FROM    (\n" +
   "        SELECT  name\n" +
     "        FROM    employee\n" +
    "        ORDER BY\n" +
   "                dbms_random.value\n" +
    "        )\n" +
   "WHERE rownum <= 1000");

     //   pw.println("<table border=1>");
             while(rs.next())
             {

            System.out.println("<br>"+"Id :"+rs.getInt("name"));
             }
//         pw.println("</table>"); 
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
    };
```

Comment: 'It doesn't work' is not an error message. What actually happens? Does it complain about the `\n` in the query string? Does it complain that you're `getInt()` and `getString()` calls are reference field names that aren't in your query? Something else?

Comment: i have just edited the code .... i m not getting tht how i can get the value after every 10 min diffrent than previous value

Comment: I don't see how a timer is going to help here - Java runs on the server while the images are displayed on the client in the browser. If you want to display new images, you'd need to trigger some sort of reload from the client side using Javascript and Ajax for example.

Comment: did u mean that if i want to show images in my webpage that are changing automaticaly after some times... i have to use javascript ??

Answer (score 1):

step 1 : fire SQL query to fetch id's from your image table

```
select image_id from ImageTable ;
```

step 2 : store id's values in some java list

```
ArrayList<Integer> IdList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while(rs.next())
{
idList.add(rs.getString(1));
}
```

step 3 : write a function to generate random no from a given list

```
int randomIdMethod(ArrayList<Integer> idList)
{
// logic
return randomImageId;
}
```

step 4 : pass the id's list to random id generator method

step 5 : retrieve the random id returned from randomIdmethod

```
Strnig newQuery = "select image fom ImageTable where imageId=randomImageId" ;
```

step 6 : fetch the image from your image table passing the is as parameter